# Unity ugui destroy gameObject random crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, destroy

unity 5.5.2p4 ugui Disable or Destroy gameObject will random crash!Is Someone else?

```
if(go != null)
{
     go.SetActive(false)
     UnityEngine.GameObject.Destroy(
        go, 0.3)
}
```

Please Help!

```
0x000000014126AB60 (Unity) UI::CanvasRenderer::CanvasHierarchyChanged 
0x000000014004A592 (Unity) MessageHandler::HandleMessage 
0x000000014004AC64 (Unity) GameObject::SendMessageAny 
0x00000001403815F2 (Unity) Transform::BroadcastMessageAny 
0x0000000141277222 (Unity) UI::Canvas::AddToManager 
0x000000014127DAA8 (Unity) UI::Canvas::AwakeFromLoad 
0x000000014052DC6A (Unity) AwakeFromLoadQueue::InvokeAwakeFromLoad 
0x000000014052DDF6 (Unity) AwakeFromLoadQueue::AwakeFromLoad 
0x000000014004BF8D (Unity) GameObject::ActivateAwakeRecursively 
0x000000014004C2B5 (Unity) GameObject::SetSelfActive 
0x0000000140E8E3C5 (Unity) GameObject_CUSTOM_SetActive
```

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/disabling-ui-crashes-at-gameobject-isactive

Comment: 5.4 is really old. You need to upgrade to the latest version

Comment: Now the project is out of order.My version is 5.5.2p4.

Is there any other way to solve this bug?

Comment: Don't use uGUI. Use NGUI.

Comment: It means the project is over again.
I hope  work out the problem.